# Can't make realm List<T> conform NSCopying

Tags: swift, list, realm, nscopying

I am trying to make List< T > conform NSCopying. I can't because:

1. @objc is not supported within extensions of generic classes.
2. I can't inherit List as it is a final class.
3. If I implement "public func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any" without marking conform NSCopying. I just get error:"...copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"

So although there is copy() in List< T >, we can never really use it.

Current I have to make copy outside of List< T >, using iteration. I can't simply using instanceOfList.copy().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary to make `List<T>` conform to `NSCopying` in order to extend it with a copy member function unless you're trying to copy it within a generic context from Objective-C. `NSCopying` is a legacy protocol that does not make a lot of sense to use in pure Swift. It is class-bound and does not have a very nice type signature.

If you're trying to use `NSCopying` in a generic context in pure Swift, consider defining your own `Copyable` protocol and extending types to conform to that. Since it isn't `@objc`, you should be fine. Existing types that already conform to `NSCopying` will require extensions to also conform to `Copyable`, but you can put the logic in an extension of `NSCopying`.

```
import Foundation

protocol Copyable {
    mutating func copy() -> Self
}

extension NSCopying {
    func copy() -> Self {
        return copy(with: nil) as! Self
    }
}

extension MyTypeThatConformsToNSCopying: Copyable { }
```

Now, I'm a little curious why you might be trying to conform `List<T>` to `NSCopying`. Are you looking for an unmanaged copy of the list? You could just use `Array(myList)` to get an `Array` from a `List`.

Comment: Yes. I was trying to make an unmanaged copy. The reason I wanted to implement NSCopying at the first place was simple. There was already a copy() inherited from NSObject.